# Is it possible to play a virtual reality game that runs inside a virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, vpn, virtual-reality

The setup idea:

- A virtual machine with the executable virtual reality game inside runs on a server.
- Someone can get access to the server from their own PC via VPN.
- They can then start the virtual machine and the game and play with the hardware (headset etc.) connected to their PC.

I just need someone knowledgeable to explain to me whether that's possible or not and why. :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't imagine that there is software that will allow you to do such a setup with little configuration effort. You would have to take care of everything yourself and build a pipeline that reads the tracking data from your HMD, sends it to the PC, which then forwards it, and then (and this might be the hardest part) passes that data on your server to an official game (if you make the game yourself, the step would be much easier).

Apart from whether it's technically possible to make something like that work somehow, it's not something you want. It won't give you a good experience, as the latency would be way too high. The HMDs themselves are already struggling to keep the latency low enough so that users don't get motion sick.